# Why is eclipse asking me to change the type of this int variable to int[]?

Tags: java, arrays, types

I was running a test code to verify my friend's argument that arrays couldn't be passed in the form of an actual array instead of the name of the array variable. Here it is:

```
 public class test 
{
int sumarr( int[] arr)
{
    int sum=0;

    int length = arr.length;

    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
    {
        sum+=arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int sum = sumarr({1,2,3});
    System.out.println(" Sum is "+sum);

}
}
```

However, eclipse says that the line `int sum=sumarr({1,2,3})` exhibits type mismatch and that i should change the type from `int` to `int[]`. How is it possible when `sumarr` returns an `int` value?

Comment: Usually you can have Eclipse fix it for you and you can see what changed. Did you try that?

Answer (score 4):

`{1,2,3}` is not an Array initialization. You should add `new int[]`, like:

```
int sum = sumarr(new int[] { 1,2,3 });
```

Comment: and the method should be static when called from main.

Comment: To add to this, as BelgianMyWaffle shows `int[] var = {1,2,3}` is valid syntax to initialize an Array variable of type int. However, passing just `{1,2,3}` to a method does not identify it as an Array of type int so that won't work.

Answer (score 3):

There are few mistakes in your code:

1. you are trying to use non-static method in static one without instance so maybe consider changing your method to static one like

   ```
   static int sumarr(int[] arr) {...}
   ```
2. you are not passing array of integers because `{1,2,3}` can be used only with declaration of variable like

   ```
   int[] someArray = {1,2,3};
   ```

   Without this declaration part compiler can't assume correct type of array which should be created here (it could be array of `long`s, `float`s and any other type of numbers).
   To solve that you need to provide actual type of array you want to use by

   ```
   new int[]{1,2,3};
   ^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   so change your code to

   ```
   int sum = sumarr(new int[]{1,2,3});
   ```